# SELECT users with certain rights

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables in MySQL

**USERS**

[image]

**USER_INFO**

[image]

**USER_RIGHTS**

[image]

**101** = read right

**102** = write right

**103** = delete right

**GROUPS**

[image]

Now when i want to select all users using INNER JOIN i do something like

```
SELECT users.id, user_info.first_name, user_info.last_name, user_rights.right
    FROM `users`
INNER 
    JOIN user_info 
    ON users.id = user_info.user_id
ORDER BY user_info.first_name;
```

and i get 2 users.

I want to make another INNER JOIN that selects members that have rights in group 1 for example, but my code dosen't work ...

```
SELECT users.id, user_info.first_name, user_info.last_name, user_rights.right
    FROM `users`
INNER 
    JOIN user_info 
    ON users.id = user_info.user_id
INNER 
    JOIN user_rights 
    ON user_rights.rights = '101' 
ORDER BY user_info.first_name;
```

The idea is to select what members has the READ right in a certain group. Hope i make myself clear.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message, not enough results, too many results? Also are you using MySQL, SQL Server, or need a solution for both? If you're using MySQL, why is this tagged with a bunch of SQL Server tags?

Comment: it gives an error, it doesn't do what i want, and this is a SQL solution, i believe it is not that different

Comment: @Row Minds: It is different. Don't tag for a specific DBMS version unless your question applies to it. The tags for mysql and sql are sufficient. Also, it's best to avoid terms like "doesn't work"; instead describe what it does and what you expected it to do.

Comment: So why not tag Oracle and DB2 and Postgres too? And why not include the actual error message you're receiving, instead of just saying "an error" even after being prompted? Help people help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Left Join with User_Rights to get all users and rights

```
SELECT users.id, 
       user_info.first_name, 
       user_info.last_name, 
       user_rights.right 
FROM   users 
       INNER JOIN user_info 
         ON users.id = user_info.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN user_rights 
         ON user_rights.user_id = users.id 
            AND user_rights.right = '101' 
       LEFT JOIN GROUPS 
         ON user_rights.group = GROUPS.group 
            AND groups.group_name = 'Human Resources' 
ORDER  BY user_info.first_name;
```

Comment: ok, and now i have to ad to this query WHERE group = Human Resources or group 1, how do i do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT users.id, user_info.first_name, user_info.last_name, user_rights.right
    FROM `users`
INNER 
    JOIN user_info 
    ON users.id = user_info.user_id
INNER 
    JOIN user_rights 
    ON user_rights.user_id = users.id 
INNER JOIN groups 
    on groups.id = user_rights.group
where user_rights.right = '101' 
and groups.group_name = 'Human Resources'
ORDER BY user_info.first_name;
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'user_rights.rights' in 'where clause'

Comment: ok, and now i have to ad to this query WHERE group = Human Resources or group 1, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a join with the group table :

```
SELECT users.id, user_info.first_name, user_info.last_name, user_rights.right
    FROM `users`
INNER 
    JOIN user_info 
    ON users.id = user_info.user_id
INNER 
    JOIN user_rights 
    ON user_rights.user_id = users.id
INNER 
    JOIN groups 
    ON user_rights.group = groups.id
WHERE user_rights.rights = '101' AND groups.group_name = 'Human Resources'
```

Comment: ok, and now i have to ad to this query WHERE group = Human Resources or group 1, how do i do that?

Comment: i have to test this with a lot of users to see if it really work, but it seems it is what i need. thanks you a lot, hope in the future i would know how to make more then 2 INNER JOINs